# Issue in fetching records from mysql database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework in php.I have a invoice table having timestamp with date and time.I want to fetch records between dates.

For eg:
I have tried the below but doesn't work

```
    $data['sdate']         = $this->input->post('sdate');
    $data['edate']              = $this->input->post('edate');
    $this->db->select('invoice_id')
             ->from('invoice')
             ->where('DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) >= ',$data[sdate])
             ->where('DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( creation_timestamp ) ) <=',$data[edate]);
     $page_data['invoice']=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

But this is not working. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you're missing quotes it should be $data['sdate'], second thing you have to make sure you're supplying MySQL formatted date YYYY-MM-DD in your sdate & edate post. to debug your query further use echo $this->db->last_query(); after your query which should show you what's in your query

Comment: I have used YYYY-MM-DD format in sdate and edate form.The page redirects to error so I could not echo the query.

Comment: Please provide the error here.

Comment: I have used form starting date and ending date in a form using jquery datepicket and when i submit the form it should list.But after form submit date1 and date2 is blank.I don't know why?

Comment: This is a totally different issue, You can use set_value to re-populate fields with posted data, but still where's the error you're getting when submitting the form?

Comment: Now I got no error.Just the date1 and date2 variables are blank.Could you pls tell me where i can reset the values.

Comment: Here's an example using form helper <?php echo form_input(['name' => 'sdate', 'value' => set_value('sdate'), 'id' => 'sdate']); ?>

Comment: where I have to give this line whether in view of form or in controller

Comment: This is in the view, it will automatically generate the field for you, you can also supply a class to enable datepicker for this.

Comment: @Rekha try to print query. Use exit to stop throwing error. `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data['sdate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('sdate'));
$data['edate'] = strtotime($this->input->post('edate'));
$this->db->select('invoice_id')
         ->from('invoice')
         ->where('creation_timestamp >= ',$data[sdate])
         ->where('creation_timestamp <= ',$data[edate]);
 $page_data['invoice']=$this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: I tried the above code.But I didnt get value for sdate and edate after form submit.I am new to codeigniter.I am struggling to submit the form.I have used the form in view and in controller function,I am fetching the posted data.But it is blank.